# For the Noahide laws, what should Noahides, who are unaware of the biblical God, do?

Tags: avodah-zarah, noachide-laws

Being a Noahide Gentile seems to be harder than it looks. Noahides must follow the seven commandments. I wonder what happens to those innocent peoples who practice polytheistic, traditional folk religions and are unaware of the biblical God. From a Jewish point-of-view, they would be just worshiping idols? Wouldn't that be a little tough on those gentiles?