# Does the first Noahide Law prohibit idolatry or being an atheist?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, noachide-laws, faith-bitachon-emunah, noahidism

Does the first Law of Noach prohibit idolatry or being an atheist, or both?

In [some](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68295/is-idolatry-one-of-the-noachide-laws-there-is-a-discrepancy-between-websites?rq=1) formulations of the 7 Noahide Laws, the first law is given as "Denying G-d" (or similar). In others, it is described as "idolatry." I have no doubt that idolatry is indeed forbidden by the Noahide laws, but is there a broader meaning to the first law that would also prohibit, say, disbelief in G-d?

Related: [For the Noahide laws, what should Noahides, who are unaware of the biblical God, do?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/for-the-noahide-laws-what-should-noahides-who-are-unaware-of-the-biblical-god)

[Do non-Jewish children taken captive lose the obligation to be Bnei Noach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29878/do-non-jewish-children-taken-captive-lose-the-obligation-to-be-bnei-noach)